# MongoDB+Nodejs reads are not distributed across replicaset members with readpreference as NEAREST

Tags: mongodb

I had a replica set with primary/secondary and read preference as NEAREST. Through *MongoStat*, I can see that requests are going to the replica set member where the mongod instance and nodejs is running and not to the other member on a different aws instance. Pinging is not enabled between the two. I can also verify that the other instance is accessible by changing the read preference. Working fine with my java client. Should the other instance be ping-able for read sharing? SecondaryAcceptableLatencyMS is set at 500.
Here is the sample code snippet I am trying to execute.

```
var replSet = new ReplSetServers( [
    new Server( "localhost", 27017, { auto_reconnect: true, native_parser: true, slaveOk: true } ),
    new Server( "<replmem1>", 27017, { auto_reconnect: true, native_parser: true, slaveOk: true } ),
    new Server( "<replmem2>", 27018, { auto_reconnect: true, native_parser: true, slaveOk: true } )
  ],
  {read_secondary:true, secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS:500 }
);


var dbCon = new Db("emails_" + postParams["campaign_id"], replSet, {safe: true, readPreference: mongo.ReadPreference.NEAREST});
    dbCon.open(function(err, db) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not documented well yet but a `strategy` option must be specified when using NEAREST.

```
var replSet = new ReplSetServers( [
    new Server( "localhost", 27017, { auto_reconnect: true, native_parser: true, slaveOk: true } ),
    new Server( "<replmem1>", 27017, { auto_reconnect: true, native_parser: true, slaveOk: true } ),
    new Server( "<replmem2>", 27018, { auto_reconnect: true, native_parser: true, slaveOk: true } )
  ],
  {read_secondary:true, secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS:500, stragegy: 'ping' }
);
```

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_1and2_2.html#read-preferences

Comment: adding strategy 'ping' is not making reads share. Should the other instance be ping-able to use this strategy? what are different strategies available?

Comment: dig through the code and found that there are two strategies one is 'ping' and the other other one is 'statistical' if none is mentioned then default is null which goes to round-robin mode.

Comment: I did not see how the servers are selected in round-robin manner in the code.

Comment: there is a [bug](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues/878) in the driver related to NEAREST where a random secondary is always chosen instead of the nearest one. a fix is on the way.